# Is it possible to implement a TCP/IP network over DECT?

Tags: ip, wifi

I am working at a site where DECT is implemented on Mobile Devices, and I am wondering if it is possible to setup a TCP/IP network using DECT as the data transmission layer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to has been done : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net3

The question is wether there are still many products which are compatible.

If the firmware of your mobile device is closed, you most likely can't add a new function... and if it is opened, you have to find and pay someone to implement it !

Comment: shortly said, possibly? Sure. Should you do it? No. Use an exit strategy (waterfalls method) for your dect issue